# Exception in postVisitDirectory; how to trigger it

Tags: java, filesystems, nio

Directly from this [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html#postVisitDirectory%28T,%20java.io.IOException%29) here is the description of postVisitDirectory method:

> postVisitDirectory
>
> FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(T dir,
>                                    IOException exc)
>                                      throws IOException
>
> Invoked for a directory after entries in the directory, and all of
>   their descendants, have been visited. This method is also invoked when
>   iteration of the directory completes prematurely (by a visitFile
>   method returning SKIP_SIBLINGS, or an I/O error when iterating over
>   the directory).

I would like to test the last part of this description: "or an I/O error when iterating over the directory".

```
This is my postVisitDirectory():

    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException io)
    {
    System.out.println(dir.getFileName());
    if (io!=null)
    {
        System.err.println("IT IS NOT NULL!");
    }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;    
    }
```

I would like to trigger "IT IS NOT NULL" in the `postVisitDirectory` method.
Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you use the printStackTrace() on your exception and show us the details of that exception ... for example add to your code (for now) if(io!=null) ioprintSTackTrace()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried throw a custom `IOException` in `visitFile()` and rethrow it in `visitFileFailed()` to check if it is propagated to `postVisitDirectory()`? Else try make a file not accessible or delete directory you are iterating for.

Comment: I would like to test a case in which the parameter IOException io gets actually used in the method postVisitDirectory. I want just to test it I do not need to use that exception.

Comment: as the API says:`This method is also invoked when iteration of the directory completes prematurely (by a visitFile method returning SKIP_SIBLINGS, or an I/O error when iterating over the directory).` Therefore as I asked in the question, I would like to know a case in which an I/O error when iterating over the directory happens

Comment: in order to see (test) whether or not postVisitDirectory gets actually called

Comment: i think that it's going to be called visitFileFailed in anycase you described in your answer, however i'll give a shot to delete the directory while iterating